# Can you run Snow Leopard Server on a VM?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, osx-snow-leopard, osx-server

I'm thinking of buying a mac mini server for my email needs (small office server for 999 with all the features i want build in)

I wanted to give it a test drive before i commit so i was thinking "hey this sounds like the perfect job for a vm" however i havent been able to see any examples of running snow lepoard server on a vm

does anyone know if its possible and/or there is a premade vm package to test it out with?

Answer (score 2):

Both Paralells and VM Ware Fusion allow you to make a Virtual Machine of Snow Leopard Server since Apple recently changed the License agreement for Server. You still can't virtualize an OS X client however.

Right now this will only work on Mac Hardware and you have to have bought a license for each copy of Snow Leopard server. All that means is that you can't have the Host OS and the virtual machine use the same license of Snow Leopard Server. If you care about license agreements.

Unless you have multiple servers I would just get the mac mini.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Server as a VM host on Mac OS X Client ( either 10.5 or 10.6 ). VMWare Fusion is much better for stability IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machines are just that, virtual. It's a copy of the operating system on disk and run as an application within a sandbox. If you were to use VMWare Fusion on a Mac or just VMWare on Windows you could install and try out Snow Leopard on it.

I use my virtual machines for playing with Linux distros and bug checking in IE. I don't think there is an operating system that can't be run as a virtual machine.

Comment: The issue is that OS X uses EFI instead of BIOS which is often not supported, and the major VM manufacturers have a gentleman's agreement with Apple to not allow the running of OS X clients.